Differentiability of a bivariate Lipschitz function
Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a Lipschitz continuous function in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and which is concave in $x$, uniformly in $y$. By Rademacher's theorem, $f$ is differentiable almost everywhere.
Assume further that in a point $(x_0,y_0)$ where $f$ is potentially non differentiable, we know that:

$x\mapsto \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y_0)$ is continuous in $x_0$
$y\mapsto \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y)$ is continuous in $y_0$
limits $\lim \limits_{y \rightarrow y_0^+} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y)$ and $\lim \limits_{y \rightarrow y_0^-} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y)$ exist.

Does this imply $\lim \limits_{y \rightarrow y_0^+} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y)=\lim \limits_{y \rightarrow y_0^-} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y)$? Or is there a counter-example where the former limits are not equals but continuity of $f$ still holds?
